# Problem setting boundary conditions with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I have the following system of PDEs for which I have given parameters $\gamma, \tau$ and $\mu$,

$$\begin{align}
T_t = &\ \gamma\,(L +\tau F-T)\\
F_t = & -F_x-(F-LT)\\
L_t = &\ \mu L_{xx}+(F-LT)\end{align}$$

with no flux boundary conditions at $x=0$ and $x=\infty$ for $F$ and $L$. The initial conditions are $L=T=F=e^{-x^2}$. I tried to find a travelling wave solution to this problem, and I encountered an error while trying to set boundary conditions for $F$ as the order of the derivative in the boundary condition was equal to that in the given system. To solve that, I proceeded in accordance to:

[Too high differential order in boundary conditions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72489/too-high-differential-order-in-boundary-conditions)

but encountered further issues. This is my code:

```
gam = 1;
tau = 0.6;
mu = 0.2;
n = 100;
time = 10;

sys = {Derivative[0, 1][T][x, t] == 
         gam*(L[x, t] + tau*F[x, t] - T[x, t]),
       Derivative[1, 1][F][x,t] == 
         -Derivative[2, 0][F][x, t] - Derivative[1, 0][F][x, t] - 
           D[L[x, t]*T[x, t], x]),
       Derivative[0, 1][L][x, t] == 
         mu*Derivative[2, 0][L][x, t] + (F[x, t] - L[x, t]*T[x, t]),
       L[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2],
       T[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2],
       F[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2],
       Derivative[1, 0][F][0, t] == 0,
       Derivative[1, 0][F][n, t] == 0,
       Derivative[1, 0][L][0, t] == 0,
       Derivative[1, 0][L][n, t] == 0,
       Derivative[0, 1][F][0,0] == 
         -Derivative[1, 0][F][0, 0] - (F[0, 0] - L[0, 0]*T[0, 0])
   };
sol = NDSolve[sys, {T, F, L}, {x, 0, n}, {t, 0, time}];
```

I am getting the following error message:

> NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition (F^(0, 1))[0, 0] == -F[0, 0] + L[0, 0] T[0, 0] - (F^(1, 0))[0, 0] is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain. >>

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Since you had provided the idea which led to this, do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Your equations are nonlinear. Try `MethodOfLines `

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.