# NDSolve and higher derivative in bc

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

While trying to solve

```
With[{h = h[x]},
{eq, bc} = {D[h, x, x] == Sin[Pi x], {h == 0 /. x -> 0, 
 D[h, x, x] == -D[h, x] + h /. x -> 1}}];
g = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, h, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I got the error

> NDSolve::nlnum1: The function value {0.,0.31831 +(NDSolve`h$9$1^[Prime])[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72493/74763)} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} when the arguments are {0.,0.,0.31831,0.63662}.

Then I found [this trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72493/74763) so I tried

```
With[{h = h[x]},
{eq, bc} = {D[h, x, x, x] == 
 Pi Cos[Pi x], {D[h, x, x] == Sin[Pi x] /. x -> 0, 
 h == 0 /. x -> 0, D[h, x, x] == -D[h, x] + h /. x -> 1}}];
 g = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, h, {x, 0, 1}]
 Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I obtained
[image]

I guess this solution is not correct due to high values (maybe instability).

Is there a better way to solve such an equation?

Comment: for second order ode, IC/BC should not really have derivative terms in it of equal of higher than the 2.  And why do you write things this strange way? why not write `ode = h''[x] == Sin[Pi  x]` and `bc = {h[0] == 0, h''[1] == -h'[1] + h[1]}` which is much more readable and clear.

Comment: @Nasser yes I realized that, but still looking for good solutions.For the form I wrote, it's because I simplified complicated eqs.

Answer (score 5):

Your ode-system has no solution!

general solution depends on two parameters

```
H = DSolveValue[h''[x] == Sin[Pi x], h, x]
(*Function[{x}, C[1] + x C[2] - Sin[\[Pi] x]/\[Pi]^2]*)

Solve[{H[0] == 0, (H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[1] ==H[1] - Derivative[1][H][1] }, {C[1], C[2]}]
(* {} *)
```

Only bc `h[0]==1/Pi` gives a solution

```
Solve[{H[0] == 1/Pi, (H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[1] ==H[1] - Derivative[1][H][1] }, {C[1], C[2]}][[1]]
(* {C[1] -> 1/\[Pi]} *)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. This is because I simplified the eq. I can take `h[0]==1/Pi` to focus on bc issue.

Comment: @S.Euler As Nasser mentioned in hist comment `NDSolve` doesn't allow boundary conditions with order of ode!

Comment: what about approximating h'' by first oder derivative?

Comment: @S.Euler Try `DSolveValue[{h''[x] == Sin[Pi x], h[0] == 1/Pi, Sin[Pi] == h[1] - h'[1]}, h,
  x]` , but Mathematica gives an error message.